# ajax Spring liferay

Tags: ajax, spring-mvc, exception, liferay

I'm using an architetture that has: AJAX, Liferay 6.2, Spring 4.3.18.RELEASE;

From AJAX i make a call to the backend, that pass throu liferay and reach my controller;

Now, I want to generete an exception in the controller in order to reach the the failure of the ajax call; I've googled a lot but I wasn't able to find the solution.

my controller:

```
@Controller("movemementCon")
@RequestMapping("VIEW")
public class movemementCon {

@ResourceMapping("getDis")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<BenException> getImp(ResourceRequest request, ResourceResponse response, Model model) throws BenException{

return new ResponseEntity<BenException>(HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE);
}
```

But when i reach the code in javascript (the AJAX call) it ignored definitively that I've throw an exception;
The desidered behaviur is that i force to go to the error statment in the AJAX call.

Comment: But you didn't throw an exception, you returned a value.  From the AJAX perspective, this is a successful call, not a failure.

Answer (score 0):

In web browser you can't catch java errors on client side, because client doesn't know anything about backend. You have to catch that error in spring controller method and then return `ResponseEntity` with some status, response body, custom response headers, so you can notify client that something went wrong and handle it correctly there.

```
@Controller("movemementCon")
@RequestMapping("VIEW")
public class movemementCon {

    @ResourceMapping("getDis")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<SomeClass> getImp(ResourceRequest request, ResourceResponse response, Model model) {
        try{
            deleteFromDatabase(model);
        } catch(BenException e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE);
        }

        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Then in your JS read the status and execute right action.

Comment: the example I've written above is the same as you written;  If you put return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE); Ajax ignore it

Comment: AJAX ignores it only because it has no code to handle bad status. You have to use your JS lib and read the response status and do the right action